# How to tell if my LLC's registered agent has resigned?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

I run an LLC incorporated in Delaware. Since I'm not a US resident, I created it hiring the services of a website that helped me with the filing. A while ago I tried contacting them since I expected an annual fee from their part, as they are working as my registered agents, but received no reply. So basically I don't know if they're actually still fulfilling their duties as registered agents for my LLC.

My questions are:

1. How can I tell if my LLC is still compliant?
2. Even if they have not actually resigned, so they show (in paper at least, to the state of Delaware) as my registered agents yet, is there any way to tell if they're still offering their services?
3. If my LLC is not compliant due to lack of registered agent, how am I notified? How long do I have until I get fined/my company gets dissolved due to non-compliance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check if they're still listed as a valid registered agent [here](https://corp.delaware.gov/agents/).

To change your registered agent, you need to submit one of the forms listed [here](https://corp.delaware.gov/coa09/). Your new registered agent would probably provide you a prefilled form to file with all of their information, if not - you can fill it yourself.

If the registered agent resigned from being your agent they should have filed [this form](https://corp.delaware.gov/resign-w-o-appt-forms/), you can check with the DE government if it was filed by checking your LLC status [here](https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx).

I'm not sure if the LLC is going to be dissolved by the government for the lack of proper registered agent, but you may lose liability protection as you will not be in good standing with the State (which is what you have the LLC for to begin with), and you may lose lawsuits by default because of that if you end up being sued.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I checked my LLC status with the link you shared and I still see them listed as my registered agent, but I don't see them in the list of valid registered agents. What should I make of this?

Comment: @GreatDeceiver that they probably went out of business abruptly and didn't clear up their desk. Hire a new one.